# Codeigniter database connections error and db_select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I'll try to be brief and to the point.

1. I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.4. with HMVC
2. Working perfectly on localhost with `'pconnect' = FALSE;`
3. Problem at live server through shared hosting.
4. `max_user_connections = 10`. Set by the Hosting company.
5. Also added `mysql.allow_persistent = Off` to php.ini file.
6. Gives the error  `Message:  mysqli::real_connect(): (42000/1203): User <user> already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections 
   Filename:mysqli/mysqli_driver.php Line Number: 201`
7. `Line 201` is calling `mysqli::real_connect` within db_connect function of mysqli_driver
8. CI's official statement is "...CodeIgniter intelligently takes care of closing your database connections".

With `pconnect = FALSE;` and CI's "intelligent" closing of database connections, I don't see what should be causing the problem.

**EDIT**

- Was previously loading database groups through
  `$this->load->database('group', TRUE);` in each model (only one such
  call per model).
- Tried resolving above error through autoloading 'database' library and setting `$this->db->db_select('dbName');` in
  respective *controllers+models* but it's not always selecting the
  correct database when *controller+model* is loaded.
- Does anyone know how `db->db_select()` works?

Any ideas would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47160/34193

Comment: @Vickel, thx but this is for someone with mysqladmin access. Hosting service has already refused to even increase `max_user_connections` from 10, let alone set it to 0 (unlimited).

Answer (score 0):

Check your database setting inside applications/config folder.

Somewhere you had mentioned mysql and somewhere mysqli.

Remember current version of CodeIgniter doesn't support mysql.

Hope it helps